# Windows user name in angular js application with web api service

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

We have developed an angular js application and used web api as a service.

I like to use windows login user name in my application so I have called web api to get the windows user.  But I am not able to get the windows user in the web api.

The angular js application and the web api are hosted on IIS in two different ports.

Note: I am getting windows user when angular js application and the web api are hosted in the same port.

Is it possible to get the windows user name in the webapi by hosting them in the different ports.

Thanks,
Ganesh